# Executing Jar file from command line with spaces in folder name

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

```
Input File Path as argument to program

File Path : E:\TestCode\Test file space\abc.xml

Code : This code will accept the above file path as argument.

package com.org;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class FileSepratorTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filePath = args[0];    // It will take file path as E:\TestCode\Test file space\abc.xml
        try {
            System.out.println("File Path :"+filePath);  // printing file path
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath)); 
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}


Exception occurs when execute this code with space separated folder name

File Path :E:\TestCode\Test
```

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\TestCode\Test (The system cannot find the file specified)
>      at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
>      at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
>      at com.org.FileSepratorTest.main(FileSepratorTest.java:16)

It's not showing whole file path, I know I need to take this as arguments but I want to execute jar file, jar file path specified as follows

```
E:\TestCode\executable_jar>java -cp E:\TestCode\executable_jar\abc_lib -jar redmas-    migration.jar E:\TestCode\Migration Letest File\abc.xml** **in my application.
```

Comment: try with this: java -cp E:\TestCode\executable_jar\abc_lib -jar redmas-    migration.jar "E:\TestCode\Migration Letest File\abc.xml"

Comment: use double-quotes `"path"` to enclose the path

Comment: Thanks for help, Its working as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surround your file path with `" - double quote`

> E:\TestCode\executable_jar>java -cp E:\TestCode\executable_jar\abc_lib
>   -jar redmas-    migration.jar "E:\TestCode\Migration Letest File\abc.xml"